# How to automatically logout all apps in Android TV?

Tags: android, android-tv

We provide Android TV software solutions to our hotel partners. Specifically we implement default launcher where it is automatically shown on the TV screen (with nice greetings) when hotel client enters the room.

Our client recently ask us, sometimes hotel guests will login to YouTube or other apps using their own account and forget to logout, the next guest will then use those app with previous guest's credentials.

My question is, is there any way to write programs to automatically logout every app when guest check-out the room, maybe triggered by our backend? Do we need root access?
Just curious how this is normally done.

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use `pm clear com.google.android.youtube.tv` to clear user data automatically when user checkout out in your backend,  no need root access.

Hope to help you.

Comment: thanks i'll give it a try on Android TV.
I ran it on my mobile and it failed
$ pm clear com.google.android.youtube.tv
Failed
and I tried to clear app data manually but it is still logged in.

Comment: It would just clear youtube login info. But accounts are still remember on Android System. Can be found on Setting -> Accounts..

Answer (score 0):

Hi， I just try in my Android TV devices, it's working
here is my code:

```
    val accountManager = AccountManager.get(this)
    Log.d("Nathan","size ${accountManager.accounts.size}")
    accountManager.accounts.forEach {
        Log.d("Nathan","accountname :${it.name}")
        accountManager.removeAccount(it,this,callbackAccountManager, Handler())
    }  


//this is a callback        
private var callbackAccountManager = object: AccountManagerCallback<Bundle> {
    override fun run(future: AccountManagerFuture<Bundle>?) {
        Log.d("Nathan","future :${future?.result?.getBoolean(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNTS)}")
    }
}   


//permission in AndroidManifest.xml
1. root permission:android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system"
2:    
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS"/>
```

Comment: awesome! i'll give it a try.
it seems root permission is required

Comment: accountManager.accounts size is 0 on my test. Seems only visible to system app or apps which own the authType